# Python Tkinter button function call with a variable reference

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to do this

```
 WoodInt = GatherWood(WoodInt)
```

On a tkinter button?

```
 BWood = tk.Button(Top, text ="Gather Wood", command = GatherWood)
```

what I want to do is every time I press the button, `WoodInt` goes up by 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is rather unclear whet `GatherWood` does, however, one way to do this is to link your button to a command that increments `WoodInt` by 20:

```
def increment_woodint_by_20():
    global WoodInt
    Woodint += 20

WoodInt = GatherWood(WoodInt)
BWood = tk.Button(Top, text ="Gather Wood", command=increment_woodint_by_20)
...
```

Comment: I keep hearing around SO that using global and nonlocal is a bad habit... and I have many other gather buttons, and I was hoping to re-use the Gather function.

Comment: Indeed it is, however, the use of `global` here allowed to show you a simple way to address your problem. For a more elaborate solution, place the variables in a class that you can pass around and modify!

Comment: Ok, I still haven't learned about classes, so I will probably go for the global for now, Thank you for the advice